# Showing a gif with transparent background in an ImageView

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have a coloured gif image that I would like to use in my application, I imported the image into my application by dropping and dragging the gif into res/drawable.
However the transparent background turns white when it is shown in an imageview, here is my code

```
        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
```

How can I make android show the transparent background and not a white one?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to open a gif in a webview. you can put the gif file in a html file and open it in webview. also you can set your app background in html file to make your work easier.